# Redshift Super Type in Aws Glue

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I’m trying to create a continuous migration job from Aws S3 to Redshift using Aws Glue.
I wish to load object data types to Redshift as **super type** directly in Aws Glue.

However during the function `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf`, If the data contains an object data type, I get an error msg "CSV data source does not support struct data type" and I am aware of the cause of the error.

An option would be to use pyspark.sql.functions.to_json to the object data and later use json_extract_path_text() when querying the objects in Redshift.

But I hope there is an approach in AWS glue, that supports a direct transformation and loads object type data to super type (type that Amazon Redshift uses to support JSON columns).

Also, I do not want to flatten the objects, just want to keep them as is. So dynamic_frame.relationalize() is also not a suitable solution.

Any help would be greatly thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar issue to what you're experiencing, however it was not CSV data, but a JSON file instead. There was a single unstructured JSON key that could not be flattened (and also contained nested data), so I had to send it as SUPER data to Redshift. I turned the JSON key into a JSON string and flattened the rest of the keys. The function I used is in python, but nonetheless here it is.

```py
import json
json.dumps(object, indent=4)
```

I'm not entirely sure if prettifying the data with `indent` is necessary, but I believe in my case it worked. I was thereafter able to query the data as JSON in Redshift.